# Spring Boot and Kotlin: Dynamic Kafka topic listeners

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am writing a service with Sprint Boot and Kotlin. The service should listen to Kafka topics. I am using [Spring Cloud Stream](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream) for that.

What's working is having a hardcoded topic to listen to. For example in `application.yaml` I define the topic to listen:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        contentType: application/*+avro
        group: my-consumer-group
        consumer:
          useNativeDecoding: false
      # Binding-specific configs (Kafka agnostic)
      bindings:
        my_topic:
          # Topic to consume from
          destination: my_topic
```

and then access it like:

```
interface MyTopicSink {

    @Input(INPUT)
    fun input(): SubscribableChannel

    companion object {
        const val INPUT = "my_topic" # (From `application.yaml`)
    }
}

/**
 * Reads from my_topic Kafka topics.
 */
@Service
@EnableBinding(MyTopicSink::class)
class MyFancyConsumer() {
    /**
     * Listens & consumes from the my_topic.
     */
    @StreamListener(MyTopicSink.INPUT)
    fun processTopic(
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) key: String,
        @Payload payload: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record
    ) {
          log.info("Yaay, this is working")
      }
}
```

That's great and all, but does anyone know if I can make this dynamic? For example, one of my ideas is to have a list of topics defined somewhere, and then just have this consumer be dynamic. Reading from all the topics. Anyone did something similar? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a consumer that you create during code initialization or via API or something. This explains pretty well: https://medium.com/bliblidotcom-techblog/dynamic-spring-boot-kafka-consumer-af8740f2c703